# Date datatype in parse

Tags: java, android, date, parse-platform

I am trying to send date datatype in to Parse.com database.
I am neither able to send data or get any app crash message, not sure what is going on..

This is the code.

```
   buttonPlacebet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
          /**  if (currentUser != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // show the signup or login screen
            } **/

            final String Betname = etBetName.getText().toString().trim();
            final  String BetDescription = etDescription.getText().toString().trim();
            final int Betvalue = seekBarValue.getProgress();
            final String Cat1 = cat1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            final String Cat2 = cat2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            String endDate = textEndDate.getText().toString();

            // = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date convertedDate = new Date();
            try {
                convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(endDate);
                actualendDate = convertedDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
            ParseObject bets = new ParseObject("Bets");
            bets.put("BetName", Betname);
            bets.put("BetDescription", BetDescription);

            bets.put("BetValue",Betvalue);
            if(cbPvtbet.isChecked())
            {
                bets.put("PrivateBet","True");
            }
            else
            {
                bets.put("PrivateBet","False");
            }
            if(cbReal.isChecked())
            {
                bets.put("RealBet","True");
            }
            else
            {
                bets.put("RealBet","False");
            }

            bets.put("Cat1",Cat1);
            bets.put("Cat2",Cat2);

            endDate = actualendDate.toString();

            bets.put("EndDate",actualendDate);

            bets.saveInBackground();
        }
    });

}
```

I am guessing I am doing something wrong with the date datatype not converting/parsing properly. Tks

Adding Log cat (right when I press the button), but frankly there is literally nothing in the logcat that is showing up..

```
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): Process: com.techiequickie.bharath.betonanything, PID: 27738
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.techiequickie.bharath.betonanything.NewBet$1.onClick(NewBet.java:136)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
05-30 21:49:25.652: E/AndroidRuntime(27738):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Without logcat howz possible to solved issue??

Comment: added but there is literally nothing going on..

Comment: `I can't believe your app got crash without logcat?`

Comment: No my friend, that is the thing. It did not crash..

Comment: Actually I am getting null pointer exception..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79197/discussion-between-m-d-and-jackyboi).

Answer (score 0):

As your log shows **NullPointerException** try to look at all your variables, especially on the `actualendDate` cause you're trying to initialize it with date parsed from string input. And this is the place where everything's gone wrong.

Look at your sample date input: `"03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM"` and compare it with pattern you provided for SimpleDateFormat: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. They're completely different. That's why ParseException's risen and your `actualendDate` is not initialized and refers to **Null**

So the solution is to look at [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and change

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a);
```